# Live rhythm detection

Tags: algorithm, audio, signal-processing, beat-detection

***1. Is it possible to do live rhythm detection?***

It'll be great to make an app which will help people to detect the rhythm on unfamiliar song on the fly. Even if the app will be bounded to a few genres.

I.e. [Salsa Beat Machine](https://www.facebook.com/SalsaBeatMachine/app/135046673173249/?ref=page_internal), but they work offline on predefined music. Is that possible to do the same on the fly using mobile's microphone? Actually I don't need all that functionality, but only the artist who says "One, Two, Three..."

I'm new in audio processing, I've read only few articles, among them [the GameDev article](http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/programming/features/beatdetection/index.html). From this article I know "energy analisys" is not precise for complex music event with frequency subbands analisys enhacements. "Filtering  rhythm detection" is the most precise but too heavy for live streaming. ***2. Aren't modern devices powerfull enough to detect rhythm on the fly?***

I'm asking because haven't seen any similar app (only tempo detection) but there are lots of rhythm based games which allow you to use custom music. Fro example, ***3. How [BEAT MP3 2.0](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.studio7775.BeatMP3v2&hl=uk) work?*** Does it analyze music on the fly?

Comment: Do you mean time signature (e.g. 12/16), tempo (e.g. 120 BPM), or rhythm (e.g. ♪-♪-♪♪--♪-♪-♪♪♪-) ?

Comment: @m69 I mean count "One"/"Two"/"Three" due which you have to move in one or another dance. Please take a look at Salsa Beat Machie ref, there is an artist instrument there. That what I want

Answer (score 3):

Given an audio file, most contemporary mobile devices are more than powerful enough to do a lot of heavy DSP analysis (rhythm, key, genre, fingerprinting, etc.) while playing the file.  A live detector would need to categorize (or be given) the genre first and be smart enough to skip the intro and rhythm breaks.

Comparing the input audio fingerprint to a database of tune fingerprints might also work (similar to how many song recognition apps work).  Then just print out the tempo on the scoresheet if recognized and found in the database.  Training a DNN on fingerprints from a large set of sample songs from the genre might also work.

Comment: thank you for you answer! Could you please provide little bit more details since I'm a noob. 1. What are the techniques to categorize genre? 2. What's the most appropriate algorithm for rhythm autodetection in my case?

Comment: This is probably not a project of the right level of complexity for a newbie.

Comment: For academic papers on the topic, search "MIREX Audio Tempo Estimation"